# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment[this one my activity][1]

Tags: xamarin

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment[this one my activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n9Us.png)

when i'm building my app and clicking on button to show map it's showing exception in SetContentview
 please help me how to solve this error

my activity class===>
 public class MapViewActivity : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private List customerViewModelList;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.map_view);
        //FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
        customerViewModelList = (List<CustomerSummaryViewModel>)StaticObjects.GetObjectFromDictionary("CustomerSummaryViewModel");
        ImageView closePopup = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv_close);
        closePopup.Click += delegate
        {
            Finish();
        };
        mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
    }
    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        if (SFAContext.Instance!=null)
        {
            if (SFAContext.Instance.currentLocation!= null)
                markerOptions.SetPosition(new LatLng(SFAContext.Instance.currentLocation.Latitude, SFAContext.Instance.currentLocation.Longitude));
            else
            {
                markerOptions.SetPosition(new LatLng(17.4562377, 78.3679737));
            }
        }

        markerOptions.SetTitle("My Position");
        markerOptions.SetIcon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.current_position)));
        googleMap.AddMarker(markerOptions);
        try
        {
            if (customerViewModelList.Count > 0 && customerViewModelList != null)
            {
                MarkerOptions customerPosition = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < customerViewModelList.Count; i++)
                {
                    customerPosition = new MarkerOptions();

                    customerPosition.SetPosition(new LatLng(CommonFunctions.getDoubleValue(customerViewModelList[i].StoreLatitude),
                                                        CommonFunctions.getDoubleValue(customerViewModelList[i].StoreLongitude)));
                    customerPosition.SetTitle(customerViewModelList[i].StoreUID + "   " + customerViewModelList[i].StoreName);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerViewModelList[i].StoreLatitude) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerViewModelList[i].StoreLongitude))
                    {
                        googleMap.AddMarker(customerPosition);
                    }
                }

            }


            googleMap.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = true;
            googleMap.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = true;
            googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.ZoomIn());
            if (SFAContext.Instance == null)
            {

                googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(new LatLng(SFAContext.Instance.currentLocation.Latitude, SFAContext.Instance.currentLocation.Longitude), 18.0f));
            }
            else
                googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(new LatLng(17.4562377, 78.3679737), 17.0f));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

[manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n9Us.png)

[.AXML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg9LE.png)

Comment: please, don't use pictures! Paste your code and your errors as text.

Comment: how to edit our post i don't know please suggest me...?

Comment: Click on the _edit_ button at the bottom. In the post, use copy-paste. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and the help center for advices.